# Java HttpURLConnection class Program

Tags: java, constructor, httpurlconnection

I am learning Java through use of a textbook, which contains the following code describing the use of a `HttpURLConnection` ...

```
class HttpURLDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        URL hp = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection hpCon = (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection();

        // Display request method.
        System.out.println("Request method is " + hpCon.getRequestMethod());
        }
    }
```

Could someone please explain why the `hpCon` object is declared in the following way...

```
HttpURLConnection hpCon = (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection();
```

instead of declaring it like this...

```
HttpURLConnection hpCon = new HttpURLConnection();
```

The textbook author provided the following explanation, which I don't really understand...

> Java provides a subclass of URLConnection that provides support for HTTP connections.
>   This class is called HttpURLConnection. You obtain an HttpURLConnection in the same
>   way just shown, by calling openConnection( ) on a URL object, but you must cast the result
>   to HttpURLConnection. (Of course, you must make sure that you are actually opening an
>   HTTP connection.) Once you have obtained a reference to an HttpURLConnection object,
>   you can use any of the methods inherited from URLConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.net.URLConnection` is an abstract class that facilitates in communication with various types of servers via various protocols (`ftp` `http` etc).

The ***protocol specific*** subclasses are hidden inside SUN's packages and these hidden classes are responsible for the concrete implementation of the protocols.

In your example since your URL is a `http://www.google.com` by parsing the URL the internals of the URL class knows that an HTTP handler/subclass must be used.
So when you open a connection to the server `hp.openConnection();` you get a concrete instance of a class that implements the HTTP protocol.

That class is an instance of `HttpURLConnection` (actually a subclass since `HTTPURLConnection` is also `abstract` and that is why you can do:

`HttpURLConnection hpCon = (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection();` and not get class cast exception.

So with Java's design you can't do `HttpURLConnection hpCon = new HttpURLConnection(hp);` as you ask, since that is not how the designers want you to use these APIs.

You are expected to work arround `URL`s and `URLConnections` and only worry about input/output.
You shouldn't worry about the rest

Answer (score 4):

The declaration that you don't understand why not to use:

```
 HttpURLConnection hpCon = new HttpURLConnection();
```

Does not provide information about the URL to which you want to open the connection. This is the reason why you should use:

```
HttpURLConnection hpCon = new HttpURLConnection(hp);
```

Because this way the constructor knows that you want to open a connection to the url `"http://www.google.com"`.